# Get branch result of a Custom Decision Split activity

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-activity

I'm creating a custom activity and I want to get the branch result of a custom decision split activity. Someone knows how to pass it programmatically? Here is the example code on the customActivity.js **save** function of the custom activity that I'm creating:

```
payload['arguments'].execute.inArguments = [{
        "ID": "{{Event."+ eventDefinitionKey +".ID}}",
        "TransactionCode": "{{Event." + eventDefinitionKey + ".TransactionCode}}",
        "Name": Name,
        "Outcome": "{{Interaction.RestDecision-1.outcome}}"
}];
```

So in the **Outcome**, I want to get the branch result of the custom decision split. So if I used the custom activity that I'm creating in each branch it will dynamically get the branch result.

Thanks in advance.